# How to build a form/query with editable fields and aggregate values of children in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I would like to build a tabular form that has editable fields, but also shows aggregated values of the children, e.g. a form "purchase order" that shows the sum of all items contained in the purchase order.

1. I could make an aggregate query and join it to the record source query of my main form, but that would make all fields of the query read-only.
2. I could create unbound fields and populate them with DLookUps, which would work but seems to create a lot of overhead, and is sluggish in datasheet view and tabular forms.
3. I could create a combo-box for my ID field, set the row source to my aggregate query an reference these columns in other fields of my form (Controlsource = `[cboID].[Column](2)` etc.). Maybe less overhead than solution 2, but also sluggish.
4. Populating fields through code will (I think) lead to all lines in datasheet view having the same value, that changes everytime you select a new record.

I can't believe there is no more graceful solution to this.

Comment: I found a related post, the solution is more complicated that I'd hoped for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823194/how-to-build-an-editable-form-with-data-equivalent-to-a-join?rq=1

Comment: Maybe https://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp

Comment: Or try form/subform set as datasheet/subdatasheet.

Comment: I think I am going to use a read only form with a query containing all information, and have a separate form to edit information. I imagine this will also be better in terms of record locking. This way I can also use the built in filters in Datasheet view.