# Can we Modify the content of a Form ? Ms ACCESS

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

In my Access frontal base, I have a query that select certain data from an other Access database. It works fine.

Using a Form assistant I call all of the data selected using my query in the form. and it works fine.
The only issue I have, is that I want to modify the content of certain column in That form, but I can't.

Here is more details :

**To create my form**

I used a form assistant as shown below ->

[image]

I chosed the query I want and called all the columns.

**Result : **

[image]

I got the result I'm looking for except for one point is that I can't modify the form.

I ideally want to be able to only modify the 2 last columns ('Identifiant candidat' & 'Candidat Nom') But if it's not possible than being able to modify all of my form is good.

Thank you so much for your time and help

Comment: Some causes for non-updateable queries (and forms based on them): https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/non-updateable/index.html

Answer (score 0):

following your question @HansUp in the query designer this is what I have
[image]

So it's not possible to modify it

Comment: If you can't edit those fields in the query,  using a form based on the query will not allow you to edit them there either.  Could you switch to a [form/subform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b) approach for what you need?

Comment: I'm so sorry for this late answer, I actually don't have an idea on how to switch to a form or even if it's possible to do because I need to collect data from multiple forms and other queries.

Comment: Well I found a similar problem in the link bellow :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823194/how-to-build-an-editable-form-with-data-equivalent-to-a-join?rq=1

It's not an easy answer but I'll try it.
Thank you @HansUp and Andre for your time and answers ! very much appreciated 
And if you still have other easy idea regarding that please let me know